# How to make a fetch() POST request to wordpress rest api?

Tags: ajax, rest-api

I am trying to make a POST request to rest api. But I am getting  `401 Unauthorised error`. Also can someone help with handling nonce in it?

#OurPostData : Contains the title.

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.online/wp-json/wp/v2/code',{
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}),
      body:JSON.stringify(OurPostData),
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    });
```

this method below works

```
var createPost = new XMLHttpRequest();
createPost.open("POST", "https://mywebsite.online/wp-json/wp/v2/code");
createPost.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", Ajax.nonce);
createPost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
createPost.send(JSON.stringify(OurPostData));
createPost.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (createPost.readyState == 4) {
    if (createPost.status == 201) {
      alert("Success");
    } else {
      alert("Error Try Again");
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Lots of other people with this issue before - for example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/315731/7968

Comment: Also, from the official documentation on authentication: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Comment: @QStudio is there a way to do it without that way? If I am making something for the public I can't ask for them to edit htaaccess file

Comment: First, try and see if this is the issue, then consider the technical implications.

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla What is for the public? The script? Or the API endpoint?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Please don't get confused with what I said. I can use the normal ajax method to send a post request, which works. I am stuck with making the fetch method work. Just the script. https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-api-fetch/

Comment: @QStudio It was a nonce issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'X-WP-Nonce' : Ajax.nonce` Was missing that's why it was giving the error

```
  fetch('https://mywebsite.online/wp-json/wp/v2/code', {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'X-WP-Nonce' : Ajax.nonce
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify(OurPostData),
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    });
```